# FLRW Coupling to Perfect Fluid

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, cosmology, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In order to obtain the Friedmann equations from the Lagrangian formalism, as far as I understand, one way is to minimally couple a scalar field $\phi(t)$ to the FLRW metric, i.e.

$S=\int d^4 x \sqrt{-g} \bigg(R  - \frac{1}{2} g_{\alpha\beta} \partial^\alpha \phi \partial^\beta \phi - V(\phi) \bigg)$.

Then, one computes the energy-momentum tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$  of the scalar field and identifies the pressure and energy density in terms of $d\phi/dt$ and $V$, one finds that the equations of motion derived from the action above are the Friedmann equations.

My question is: can one write the coupling of FLRW gravity to a perfect fluid in the Lagrangian formalism without introducing a scalar field in this way, instead perhaps with a term like $g_{\mu\nu}T^{\mu\nu}$?

Any kind of feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have understood your question but I think you are asking about other kind of density Lagrangian for matter.

Inflation considers scalar fields(as you said):
$$ \mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2} g_{\alpha\beta}\partial^\alpha\phi\partial^\beta\phi - V(\phi) \:.$$

$\Lambda CDM$ considers perfect fluids:
$$ \mathcal{L} = -\rho \:.$$

There are some examples of different energy-momentum
tensors that occur in general relativity and cosmology. You can read the chapter 8 section 5 from the book "Einstein’s General Theory of Relativity by Øyvind Grøn Si gbjørn Hervik".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input and the reference.  I see that the $\Lambda CDM$ Lagrangian does indeed give me the Friedmann equations. But so does the one for scalar fields, since
$\rho =\frac{1}{2} \dot{\phi}^2 + V ( \phi)$ and $p = \frac{1}{2} \dot{\phi}^2 - V ( \phi)$ 
(For instance in http://www.blau.itp.unibe.ch/newlecturesGR.pdf equation 35.147). 
Could you say that these Lagrangians are related? 

Is there a way to obtain the Friedmann equations with a coupling term that is $\mathcal{L} = g_{\mu\nu} T^{\mu\nu}$?